# How to call slider move event from QT

Tags: javascript, jquery, qt, slider, qtwebkit

I'm trying to call a Javascript/JQuery slider event -in an HTML file that I use as my WebView- from QT via evaluateJavaScript by using a horizontal slider, I have a function that is called as a SLOT to the SIGNAL of valueChanged(int). I have tried

```
this->ui->browser->page()->mainFrame()->evaluateJavaScript($("#radius-slider").slider({

  min: 0,
  max: 50,


  step: 0.1,

  value: layers[currentValue].defaultRadius,

  change: function(event, ui) {

changeRadius(ui.value);

  }

}););
```

and

```
QString theJSCode = QString("changeRadius(%1)").arg(this->ui->horizontalSlider_6->value());
this->ui->browser->page()->mainFrame()->evaluateJavaScript(theJSCode);
```

to no avail. What am I getting wrong here and where should I be looking to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking for some examples, I did the following and it worked.

Javascript end:

```
function setVals(newVal){
$("#radius-slider").slider('value', newVal);
}
```

Qt end:

```
QString theJSCode = QString("setVals(%1)").arg(this->ui->horizontalSlider_6->value());
this->ui->browser->page()->mainFrame()->evaluateJavaScript(theJSCode);
```